# Cannot set TD width when viewing multiple HTML tables in Excel

Tags: php, html, css, excel, http-headers

Hello I write PHP header for downloading excel.

If I have 1 table I can set the width of `<td>` successfully  by use width attribute

but if I have two table it's not working.  How could I do? because I need multiple table in my excel page file

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=TIS-620");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report_schedule_teacher.xls"');#ชื่อไฟล์

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=TIS-620" />


</head>
<body>

    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;overflow:wrap; font-size:9pt;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">Hello1</td>
            <td width="400">Hello2</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>World1</td>
            <td>World2</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;overflow:wrap; font-size:9pt;">  
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">Why I cannot set width if I have multiple table</td>
            <td width="400">Noooo</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>kub</td>
            <td>pom</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you use width you have to write unit (px, %, etc).

Comment: still not working..

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to set width of td   but in excel page  it has problem when I have more than one table.

Comment: do you looking for <td colspan="2"> ? All tables are independent. When you change width table change width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel, when reading HTML files, really only has one HTML table. If you look at the Excel window you'll see that physically it's just a single table. If you insist on separating the data (which makes no difference to Excel) you can use multiple table bodies:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=TIS-620" />


</head>
<body>

    <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;overflow:wrap; font-size:9pt;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">Hello1</td>
            <td width="400">Hello2</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>World1</td>
            <td>World2</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="300">Why I cannot set width if I have multiple table</td>
            <td width="400">Noooo</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>kub</td>
            <td>pom</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: screenshot of Excel]

By the way, you are abusing MIME types terribly here! This document is not `application/vnd.ms-excel` or `application/xhtml+xml`, it's `text/html` and should not be saved with an XLS extension. Excel can read HTML files, but that doesn't make HTML files Excel files!